# How to use dynamic div id from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code

```
   var div = "detail"
   $(`#${div}`).html("");
```

it shows error like this

```
Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #
```

How can I use variable as id name??

Comment: from your exact example, I see no error when I try in my end. Could you try this one ``$(document).find(`#${div}`).html("");``

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the error based on your provided code (it works as expected). Are you sure that's the exact code you're using?

Comment: Thankyou FerdousTheWebCoder, it works well for me. @Ouroborus, thank you for chacking. I had mistypo somewhere else... so I was confused..

Comment: *I had mistypo somewhere else...* - so is your issue resolved?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, if you are using plain JS, you can create the variable, then use document.getElementById(variable) to find the element.

```
var div_id = "details";
document.getElementById(div_id).innerHTML = ""
```